# Probability space with countable subset such that every subset of positive measure meets the subset

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal F,  P)$ be a probability space.

## Question

What kind of condition is this: there exists a sequence $(a_n)_n \subseteq X$ such that

> $\forall$ measurable $A \subseteq X$, $P(A) > 0 \implies a_n \in A$ for some $n$.

**Context.** I'm reviewing a paper for a conference and the authors assume this condition on the probability space in order to prove a result. I was wondering if this condition has a technical name, etc. in the greater math literature.

Comment: The measure is a countable combination of atoms.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks, I should have thought of this. It's rather obvious. Indeed, such a measure must be discrete, and so the condition is extremely restrictive.

Comment: *Proof of Fedor's claim.* We show that the set compliment $X\setminus (a_n)_n$ has zero measure. Indeed, $X \setminus (a_n)_n$ (assumed measurable!) contains no $a_n$, thus by the contrapositive of condition, we must have $P(X\setminus (a_n)_n) = 0$. Thus the support of $P$ is a contained in the sequence $(a_n)_n$, and so the former must be a countable combination of atoms $\Box$. I should probably close the question...

Comment: Actually the point $\{a_n\}$ may be non-measurable. But we may denote by $c_n$ the infimum of measures of all measurable sets containing $a_n$, this infimum is realized (since the countable intersection of the sequence of minimizing sets is measurable itself), and the set $A_n$ which realizes it is an atom.

Comment: Thanks for the construction. I suspected measurability limitation of my argument; that's why I put the "(assumed measurable!)" in brackets :)